# WinUI3 navigation 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

I am **extremely** new to WinUI3 (I barely know how to make a button do something!) and Navigation is really confusing me. I have gotten the code directly from the WinUI3 gallery, and yet I cannot get navigation to work. The error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' shows when I call the `Button_Click` function.
Here is MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="safesign_win.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:safesign_win"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Frame x:Name="TheNavFrame" />
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Next</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Frame>

</Window>
```

And here is MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace testapp {
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {


            this.InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankWindow1), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight }); //error occuring here
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to navigate to a new page with the file name BlankWindow1. It's the default name, but frankly I just want to get this working. I'll worry about file names later.

I have tried repositioning the frame, adding an if statement (if MainFrame != null). Logging the value of MainFrame does provide a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frame` navigation works with `Page`s, not `Window`s. ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-frame-navigate(windows-ui-xaml-interop-typename-system-object-windows-ui-xaml-media-animation-navigationtransitioninfo)))

So, you need to create a `Page`, let's say *TestPage*, and call the `Navigate` method like this:

```cs
MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(TestPage), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new WPF window or user control named "**BlankWindow1**" that you want to navigate to. Make sure it has its own XAML file and associated code-behind file.

In your **Button_Click** event handler, you can use the Navigate method of the MainFrame frame control to navigate to the desired page. Here's an example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
         MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("BlankWindow1.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

This code snippet assumes that the XAML file for "**BlankWindow1**" is located in the same project and folder. If it's located in a different folder, you may need to adjust the URI accordingly.